# loading and parsing a file with JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, parsing

I want to load an external file using AJAX GET and then parse it for the relevant information on it leaving out all the comments.

file: stuff.conf

```
: This is the list
: of colors needed

#5d3939 : nice  
#9e1818 : ugly!
#cd7979
#409c81
#6e6f14 : ok...
```

I want the hex colours in an array.

Please help!

Comment: Please provide any attempts you have made at solving this problem before asking for help.  Questions saying I have problem x give me solution y for it generally do not get much attention on Stackoverflow.  If you make an honest attempt at solving the problem and explain the issues you are having someone is bound to help you find resolve.

Comment: @Chris thank you for noticing that I have no clue on how to solve this. Something or anything is more than what I have at the moment. I know how to parse data from an xml or json file, this isnt the case. I've been looking into different stuff like peg.js but I can honestly say that I dont get how it works. Was just trying to keep it short.

Comment: Well, just use a regex on the response string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var arr = response.match(/\#[a-f0-9]{6}/gi);
```

where `response` is your Ajax response string.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/RnPS3/1/

Comment: Give a man a fish, feed him for a day.  Teach a man to fish, feed him for life.

Comment: @Chris Who am I, Jesus? `:)` Explaining/teaching regular expressions is not an efficient task, they're way to abstract. I recommend this [great article at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own JS to parse any type of data format.  But, the somewhat standard way to interchange data like this with the least hassle is to put the data in the [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format with the color values in an array (or whatever format you want them to end up on).  You then read the contents of the file into a string variable and then call a JSON parser.  The return value of the parser will be an array of color values (if that's how you format the JSON).  The latest browsers have [JSON parsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON) built in.  For cross-browser compatibility with older browsers, you can either use a parser in one of the common libraries like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) or [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/json/) or find [code on the web](http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/) to add just a JSON parser.